# Trying to use $.each jquery iterator. What is the difference between these two?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

vertices is an array of google.maps.LatLng objects, so they should be returning latlng points. It works just fine for the first code snipet. I am having problems when using the second.

```
// Iterate over the vertices.
for (var index =0; index < vertices.length; index++) {
  var value = vertices.getAt(index);
  contentString += "<br />" + "Coordinate: " + index + "<br />" + value.lat() +"," + value.lng();
      }
```

I feel like this code should mean the exact same thing, but when I use the each iterator I get a javascript error :  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined**

```
  $.each(vertices, function(index, value){
    contentString += "<br />" + "Coordinate: " + index + "<br />" + value.lat() +"," + value.lng();
  });
```

Comment: Your second code snippet looks like it should work just fine. Can you give more context? How is the vertices array being defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws an error because vertices is not a normal javascript array (there is no getAt method on the Array object in Javascript). As per Google docs:

> A polyline specifies a series of coordinates as an array of LatLng objects. To retrieve these coordinates, call the Polyline's getPath(), which will return an array of type MVCArray. 
>   Note: you cannot simply retrieve the ith element of an array by using the syntax mvcArray[i]; you must use mvcArray.getAt(i).

So you should still have:

```
$.each(vertices, function(i) { var value = vertices.getAt(i); ... });
```

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense. I had read that earlier, completely forgot about it. So I just need to include getAT . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*If* you were iterating over a normal array, these would be functionally very similar, and your second version would work. But it looks like you're iterating over a [MVCArray](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCArray), probably from `polyline.getPath`, and that's **not** an array.

It looks from the docs like you can call `.getArray()` to get the base array of vertices:

```
$.each(vertices.getArray(), function(index, value){
    contentString += "<br />" + "Coordinate: " + index + "<br />" + value.lat() +"," + value.lng();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter runs a function that also provides you a new scope.

You may not know this but the `var value` you declared inside the for is actually declared on the same scope as the for itself (it's parent) ..

[JavaScript has no block scope](http://www.tigraine.at/2011/05/05/javascript-scope/) but only function scope. So any var that is not declared near the beginning of the function is actually declared for the whole function, even it it's nested inside an if or loop.

Also, you don't get the browser abstraction jQuery provides. jQuery will detect what browser you run on and may choose a more performant path to execute your foreach, while the other will always use Array.getAt - even if there may be a better way to do that (let's say a browser starts providing a native function for example - always assuming you update jQuery)

In short: The jQuery guys know a lot more about browsers and their quirks than you do, and their way provides you with a loop scope for free. Writing your own is more error prone and can end up less efficient.

Comment: Looping with a function, as with `$.each()`, is pretty much guaranteed to be slower than a normal `for` or `while` loop because of the function call overhead, not to mention all the fancy stuff that jQuery does under the hood.

Comment: Yes - but especially with engines like tracemonkey and V8 JavaScript speed is not really an issue - while the lacking scope actually is.
That's also why I started the answer with the scope issue because the performance is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Even on chrome, if he's using thousands of elements he could save a significant amount of time by using pure javascript.

Comment: What is out of scope though? The vertices array? It is iterating the correct amount of times telling me that it is grabbing the correct array. The vertices array has six objects in it and the each iterator is iterating 0-5. It is just returning the values as undefined; that is why .lat() will not work.

Comment: Nothing is out of scope. You'll run into issues if you are using the variable `value` again outside of the loop. JavaScript has no concept of block scope so the var value inside the loop is effectively defined outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You first need to be sure what google api is returning. means when you use this

```
$.each(vertices, function(index, value){
    for(var i in value){
           alert('key =>'+i+' value=>'+value[i]);
    }
  });
```

This will give you the proper understanding of what google api is returning and are you able to call .lng() and .lat() function

Comment: I am getting the correct index values. It is just returning the values as undefined.